# xelatex and pgfpages compatibility

Tags: xetex, paper-size, incompatibility, pgfpages

I've just switched from pdflatex to xelatex for my lectures to take advantage of the `unicode-math` package so that I can change the colours of all my mathematics.  When compiling the "handout" version last night, I found that it didn't work as I expected.  I use the `pgfpages` package to produce the handout as a 4-up document (with a nice box round each frame) to save paper.  But the page size in the resulting document was that of one slide, not a full a4 piece of paper.  A little googling led me to a quick fix on [tug](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2008-November/011184.html):

```
\newlength\hackpaperwidth \hackpaperwidth210mm
\newlength\hackpaperheight \hackpaperheight297mm
\RequirePackage{everyshi}
\EveryShipout{%
 \special{papersize=\the\hackpaperwidth,\the\hackpaperheight}}
```

with the comment (from the author):

> Probably not the cleanest way of doing things, so if someone has a
>   better idea and/or can locate the bug exactly, comments welcome.

There were no follow-up comments, but it was dated November 2008.  In June 2009, there's a similar-looking problem on the xetex mailing list with this response:

> That's a reported (and probably not fixed yet) problem in pgfpages. Use this
>   to tell pgfpages how to set page sizes in XeLaTeX:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand\pgfsetupphysicalpagesizes{%
>     \pdfpagewidth\pgfphysicalwidth\pdfpageheight\pgfphysicalheight%
> }
> ```

(These are (linked from) the top two hits on google for `xelatex pgfpages`).

My *real* question is: is this going to get fixed? But that's not a good tex.SE question.  So my attempt to make it into a good question is:

> The second of the above seems the better of the two.  Is that the best way to fix this problem?

PS The MWE from the first linked post is still a suitable one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{A} foo}
\frame{\frametitle{B} bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this up so well.  I'm having the same issue and it looks like I have to use the same workaround.

Comment: @Matthew: You mean that _you_ are using coloured letters in maths as well?  Only kidding.  I'm still using the workaround too.

Comment: No, xetex and pgfpages...but I think you knew that.`:-P`

Answer (score 1):

Use option dvipdfm:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfm]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{A} foo}
\frame{\frametitle{B} bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my first test, that just fixed it for the first page but all the other pages were as before (but that was a test on a complicated document so I'll try it on the MWE too).

Comment: Using this option with XeLaTex throws the following error for the package hyperref: "Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm', because XeTeX is running.Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm' because XeTeX is running." Does anybody know if this is another incompatibility?

Comment: @Ricardo Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, @JerryWho. It is a matter of redefining the value for the physical page:     \usepackage{pgfpages}
    \renewcommand\pgfsetupphysicalpagesizes
        {\pdfpagewidth\pgfphysicalwidth\pdfpageheight\pgfphysicalheight}
    \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

Comment: If you add that in the preamble of your xelatex beamer document it should work... for me it works!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question “is this ever going to get fixed?” is *yes*.  Because your MWE works fine for me as of now.  I don't know when the bug got fixed.

Moreover, the `\renewcommand\pgfsetupphysicalpagesizes` workaround now produces unexpected behavior.  The physical page is clipped to a normal slide's dimension, which means most of the handout content is invisible.  If I apply it to your MWE, I get a page shaped like a regular slide (not A4), with one frame that has its right and bottom edges cut off.

[image: MWE output]

I discovered this because a personal class file I wrote back in 2011 stopped working, and it was these two lines that were the culprit.